# MySQL/PHP - Display Recent Date

Tags: php, mysql

I was able to apply this line onto phpMyAdmin and it worked just fine.

```
    SELECT id, date_format(`date`, '%m.%d.%Y') as `date` FROM TABLE ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
```

The problem is that when I added the rest of the code, the recent date shows up blank on the webpage. Am I missing something in this code?

```
    <?php        
    $query = "SELECT id, date_format(`date`, '%m.%d.%Y') as `date` FROM TABLE ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    echo "$date";
    ?>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

. Try this

```
$query = "SELECT id, date_format(`date`, '%m.%d.%Y') as `date` FROM TABLE ORDER BY.  date DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
$date = $r['date']; 
echo "$date";
```

Comment: While the code may solve the problem, there's no explanation to go with it. Why don't you spend another minute to explain your solution and make this a great answer?

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set $date variable. You need to use mysql_fetch_array function for your $result variable.

Ex:
`

```
$query = "SELECT id, date_format('date', '%m.%d.%Y') as 'date' FROM TABLE ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1";

$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
 print_r($row); }
```

`

Comment: Ahh, I see now what I was missing. Thank you, I'll keep this in mind!